# aggregation on fields values (regex)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to perform an aggregation to group documents by the first two letters of a specific field value.

I successfully aggreated my documents by a specific field name, but i don't know how to work with the values.

For example, for the docs:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jog"
  },
  {
    "name": "James"
  },
  {
    "name": "Robert"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jessica"
  }
]
```

I would like to get the following response:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Jo",
    "doc_count": 2 
  },
  {
    "key": "Ja",
    "doc_count": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "Ro",
    "doc_count": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "Je",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

Is there an aggregation query able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `terms` aggregation with a script instead of a field, like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "first_two": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc.name.value?.size() >=2 ? doc.name.value?.substring(0, 2) : doc.name.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if your `name` fields all have at least two characters, the script could simply be `doc.name.value?.substring(0, 2)`. My script above accounts for single character names.

Also make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.